# Accessing gridview events inside pages in a Frame

Tags: wpf, gridview, frame

Issue: I have a Frame that Frame Holds a pages
That page has a gridview control, I can design the grid, I have connected it to a database.It does not however have the default events of select, and highlight a row so that I can select a record and do what I want with it. Why?

Comment: From the amount of information you have supplied; my magic eight ball says you are doing it wrong or you skipped that part of the `GridView` documentation. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) also your `DataGridView` tag is missing your target `GridView` audience, they are two different things.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a problem that requires code to solve. There is a simple explanation I just cant remember and I was hoping someone would. So maybe I didn't present it right. I have a frame inside the frame there is a page on that page is a datagrid I cannot use the default out of the box click and highlight events. I can attach it to a db I can design it but the default events will not work. Why? There is a rule I am breaking that is causing it to behave this way.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Although WPF allows you to put a page in a frame controls can only be used in Windows so you have to make a single page application using the one window. You have to make it look like your navigating when all that's happening is your switching out controls in the main window.  So a page in a frame really only allows you to show an image because it's static. All research directs you to MVVM pattern.                                         Take a look here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-Build-Manage-and-fdd0074a#content